# Как создавть спавн врагов по очереди в Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть такая часть кода:

```py
def zombie_wave(zombie):
    zombie_wave = []
    if not zombie_wave:
        zombie.draw()
        zombie_wave.append('zombie')
```

Идея заключалась в том, чтобы был список, в котором существовали мобы:

- Когда врагов нет - появляется один враг и добавляется в список.
- Когда погибается - элемент удаляется и появляется новый.

Но у меня что-то не сходится. Вот код самих врагов:

```py
import pygame, random

class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Zombie, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/zombie.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 800
        self.rect.y = random.randint(0, 400)
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Вот код основной программы запуска:

```py
import pygame, controls
from turret import Turret
from pygame.sprite import Group
from zombie import Zombie


def start():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Убийца зомбаков")
    background = (0, 0, 0)
    turret = Turret(screen)
    bullets = Group()
    zombie = Zombie(screen)
    while True:
        controls.events(screen, turret, bullets)
        turret.update_pos()
        controls.zombie_wave(zombie)
        controls.update(background, screen, turret, zombie, bullets)
        controls.update_bullets(bullets)

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте какой-нибудь класс для контроля за зомбаками.

Я так понимаю этот класс надо разместить в модуле `controls`:

```
class Zombies:
  zombies = {}
  screen = None

  def __init__(self, screen):
      self.screen = screen

  # Зомби убит - вычеркиваем
  def killed(self, zombie):
      # id(zombie) - получение адреса объекта
      del self.zombies[id(zombie)]

  # создаем нового зомби
  def create(self):
      z = Zombie(self.screen)
      self.zombies[id(z)] = z
      z.draw()

  # Все зомби в наличии
  def all(self):
      return self.zombies.values()

...

def start():

  pygame.init()
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))

  # Создаем логово зомбаков раньше главного цикла приложения
  # и теперь никто, никуда не денется
  zombies = controls.Zombies(screen)

  while True:
      #...
```